# Async and timeouts in a webapi (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, webapi

I have the following route in my .NET WebAPI controller :

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("insert")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Insert(Customer customer)
{
    customer.InsertUser = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_currentUserService.UserId) ? "api" : _currentUserService.UserId;

    try
    {
        using (CustomerBC customerBC = new())
        {
            var task = Task.Run(() => customerBC.NewItem(customer));
            await task;
        }
        return Ok(await Result<Customer>.SuccessAsync(customer));
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        List<string> messages = new()
        {
            string.Format("Error: {0},Source : {1}", ex.Message, ex.Source)
        };
        return Ok(Result<Customer>.FailAsync(messages));
    }
}
```

I don't have access to modify the database code, and it is not designed to have awaitable results.
So, I decided to do a `Task.Run` in my controller.

Now, two questions arise :

1). What happens when i don't have connection at all to my database ? Right now, it seems that when i make a call, it just stays for a long time waiting for a response.
Can i add a timeout in my controller ? Let's say I want to wait 60 seconds, and after that throw an exception or something like that ?

2). What happens if a user wants to "Cancel" the request ? How can i implement the `CancellationToken` in this case ? All examples i found, refer to passing the token further to other entities like EntityFramework. But how can i do this in my scenario?

Comment: What benefit do you expect from using `Task.Run` here?

Comment: Consumers of this endpoint are responsible for asynchronously awaiting to avoid blocking.
Also with this implementation there is no unnecessary thread switching.

Comment: DB's have their  own time-out,  the fact your Web wpi can't reach your database is more of a fundamental problem that you should be working on first

Comment: @TheGeneral
I don't have that issue. I just want to simulate what happens when there is no connection at all, and how can I communicate this to the UI.

Comment: If you were to use the native asnc calls of your dB, you could also pass a cancellation token and time that out. However spinning up task to pass a cancellation token is possibe but a little wasteful in a Web service,  I truly think you need to rethink your problem and constraints

Comment: Can't do that,  as I cannot modify the DB access library, unfortunately.

Comment: Then If you really want to create spurious code, and can't modify db time-outs (not that you really should) , then pass a cancellation token  with a time-out to your task. However I think you need to talk through your design problems and what your trying to do to your senior devs.